# Will a bigger monitor with the same resolution have an impact on performance?

Tags: resolution

I'm aware that when you increase the resolution of a monitor you tend to see a drop in frames per seconds when running 3d applications (like games, for example), but do you also see a drop in performance if you get a bigger monitor but stay at the same resolution?

Comment: The question title should be more like "Will a bigger monitor with same resolution have an impact on performance?" instead of "Question about..."

Comment: Alright, changed that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The physical size of the monitor is of no consequence to your computer. The signal that comes out of your computer does not change depending on how physically big the display is, only on the resolution (640x480 or 1024x768) and refresh rate (60Hz, 50Hz, 72hz) of your display. You can use a 17 inch LCD display @1024x768 or a projector putting an image out onto a 10 foot wide movie screen, it's still the same signal.

The only thing that matters is how much data it has construct for every frame. Given a constant frame rate (say, 30 fps in a game) a 640x480 display requires a lot less data per frame than a 1024x768 display.

Now, if the computer doesn't have enough CPU to calculate everything in the time given (1/30th of a second), then it's not going to be updating the frames on time (30 times per second), and you might notice it. If it happens seldom enough, or it's constant enough, you might not.

Answer (score 2):

The performance is primarily tied to the resolution of the image not the size of the screen used to display the image.

You should get the same frame rate for a 1024 x 768 image displayed on a 21" monitor as you do on a 20" monitor (for example), assuming that if they are LCD monitors they have the same native resolution.

You might get more blurring on one monitor rather than the other due to the speed at which it can respond to changes in the image - this is the monitor's response time.

You should always run LCD monitors at their native resolution as this gives the best quality image.

Comment: I'm not sure though if there is not a drop for LCD screens, when they are not running in native resolution, I heard things like this, so I wasn't sure what to answer.

Comment: But anyway, it is probably negligible compared to the drop from a higher resolution.

Comment: Good point there.

Comment: According to the Wikipedia article (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Native_resolution), when a LCD screen is used below its native resolution, there is no performance drop. However, since it uses a fixed number of pixels, it relies on interpolation for lower resolutions, which can lead to a loss of quality, but not of performances.

Answer (score 0):

3D (or any other) performance will be completely unaffected by a change in monitor size if the resolution is unchanged.